# Scala Sorting list of two different objects with same fields in abstract class extensions

Tags: scala

Suppose I have:

```
object test{
abstract class Base
```

Then two case classes alpha and beta that extend Base, written:

```
case class alpha(num: Int, other: String) extends Base
case class beta(num:Int, other_two: String) extends Base
```

Then say I have a list of Base objects, `List[Base]`.

Some of those objects are alpha, and some are  beta. I want to sort them by the field `num` (the common field between alpha and beta objects).

From what I've read/googled everybody and their grandmother suggests doing the following:

```
val i: List[Base] =  List(alpha(4,"test"),beta(2,"test_two")).sortby(_.num)
```

However, this doesn't work. what does work is:

```
val j: List[Base] =List(alpha(4,"test"),beta(2,"test_two")).sortWith(num(_) < num(_)) 

}
```

My question is why does the former not work and why does the latter work?

Comment: not sure if this matters, but in my code the abstract and case classes are encloses in an object. so they are inner classes

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question and add more complete/compilable code examples. The `List` object has no `sortBy()`/`sortWith()` method (is that the name you gave your variable?), and your `sortWith()` example isn't real Scala code.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you claim SortWith() is not a valid method for a list object? List(10, 5, 8, 1, 7).sortWith(_ < _) --- that seems to compile and run just fine. If I was unclear that List is just the normal scala list object, i apologize!

Comment: @jwvh ..............

Comment: The `sort` methods are valid on any `List` instance (a `List` object) but not on _the_ `List` companion object. Example: `List.fill(2)(4)` is valid but `List(1,2).fill(3)` is not. The `List` companion object has a `fill` method. `List` instances do not.

Comment: @jwvh do my changes above help with understanding the problem?

Comment: It's still not valid Scala code. If you've got code that "does work" then post it so that we can copy-and-paste it to verify what you're seeing.

Comment: ok, now the code has been edited to be much closer to usable scala code. you can copy and paste the val i and val j in separate batches to see their results. though now i am getting an error with the sortwith method option not being able to recognize the num field.  "error: not found: value num". any suggestions as to how you would sort the list of base objects?

Comment: @jwvh ............

Answer (score 1):

You can declare in your base class that subclasses are supposed to have a `num` value:

```
abstract class Base {
  val num: Int
}
```

and then use your second variant

```
val i: List[Base] =  List(alpha(4,"test"),beta(2,"test_two")).sortBy(_.num)
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st example doesn't work because `Base` has no `.num` member. Even though all the elements of the `List` might have `.num` members, the compiler has been told to treat them as type `Base` so `_.num` isn't valid.

The `sortWith()` example will only work if a method `num()` exists. Something like this.

```
def num(x: Base): Int = x match {
  case a: alpha => a.num   // BTW, class names should be capitalized
  case b: beta  => b.num
  case _ => 0
}
```

Now the 2nd example compiles and works because the `num()` method is determining the type and extracting the `.num` member, if it exists. But if that's the case then your first example can also be made to work.

```
val i: List[Base] = List(alpha(4,"test"),beta(2,"test_two")).sortBy(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the solution as suggested by @Harald, the `sortWith` method will work if the supplied function is modified as follows:

```
abstract class Base {
  val num: Int
}

case class Alpha(num: Int, other: String) extends Base
case class Beta(num: Int, other_two: String) extends Base

List(Alpha(4, "test"), Beta(2, "test_two")).sortWith(_.num < _.num)
res1: List[Product with Serializable with Base] = List(Beta(2,test_two), Alpha(4,test))

// OR

List(Alpha(4, "test"), Beta(2, "test_two")).sortWith((x, y) => x.num < y.num)
res2: List[Product with Serializable with Base] = List(Beta(2,test_two), Alpha(4,test))
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful